# React Router rendering empty div

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

The `app` div is empty. The only thing inside it is a `noscript` tag.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var reactRouter = require('react-router');

var Router = reactRouter.Router;
var DefaultRoute = reactRouter.DefaultRoute;
var Route = reactRouter.Route; 
var RouteHandler = reactRouter.RouteHandler;
var Link = reactRouter.Link;

var LoginHandler = require('./components/LoginHandler.jsx');

var AppComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <nav>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="login">Login</Link>
            <RouteHandler/>
            </nav>
        )
    }
});

var routes = (  
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={AppComponent}></Route>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes}/>, document.getElementById('app'));`
```

Comment: not sure if it matters, but don't you need a ';' after the ) that would close the return() statement?

Comment: @CotyEmbry no, a semi-colon in that spot would make no difference, as the new-line in that spot is also a line-ending terminator

Comment: @bounty can you post your package.json, or your react-router version. it appears you are using the api from an older version and perhaps you have installed a newer one

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing handler with component in the `Route` tag:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var reactRouter = require('react-router');

var Router = reactRouter.Router;
var DefaultRoute = reactRouter.DefaultRoute;
var Route = reactRouter.Route; 
var RouteHandler = reactRouter.RouteHandler;
var Link = reactRouter.Link;

var LoginHandler = require('./components/LoginHandler.jsx');

var AppComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <nav>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="login">Login</Link>
            <RouteHandler/>
            </nav>
        )
    }
});

var routes = (  
    <Route name="app" path="/" component={AppComponent}></Route>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```